# /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 10747 Segmentation fault: 11 $HTTPD "$@"

Tags: macos, apache2, devops

Cannot start apache on mac ox x 10.13.

**/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 92: 10747 Segmentation fault: 11  $HTTPD "$@"**

Comment: Possibly a module gone bad. Turn off the loading of all modules of first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing php7.

I have just commented `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in the `httpd.conf` file and now all is working.